# In my asp.net-mvc file, how can I move my javascript to a seperate js file?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a bunch of javascript inside my view and its getting quite large so I want to move it to a separate js file.  The one issue I have is that I have this line:

```
 var tags = <%= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model.Tags) %>;
```

which I obviously can't just copy over since it has the server side asp.net-mvc tags.   What is the recommended way to deal with that:

1. Keep this one function inside the aspx page and have the javascript from the seperate js file call that function?
2. Other??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is have a JavaScript object contain all the information you get from the controller and pass it through a javascript function which is located in the external javascript file. You can also pass other information through the options variable.

Example:

```
 var options = {
    tags: <%= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model.Tags) %>
 };
 initPage(options);
```

Usage:

```
function initPage(options) {
    console.log(options.tags);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends a lot on the way you want to use it and the level of repeating.

Some thoughts:

1. The `tags` are static. Then I guess then don't really need to be in the model. So you can move them into a new Controller action which outputs the scipt. You can call this action in the `<script>` part of your view.
2. The `tags` are changing very frequently (maybe even at every page load). Then there is no gain in moving this in a separate script file.

Answer (score 0):

If you set up your javascript file with proper closures, you can expose a property (or better yet, a parameter to the object/method) with which to pass that information along when you call that function.

Your Javascript would need to be something like this:

```
var JsFile = (function() {
    var tags;
    // list all of your methods here.

    return {
        var setTags = function(_tags) {
            tags = _tags;
        }
    };
})();
```